# Why is there a empty rectangle next to my accordion menu in bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[here is the image of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54bjW.png) there seems to be something wrong in the display of my content, the empty triangle which normally shows for incorrect links of images is showing, but I have no image there and fontawsome icons are working fine, what could this be?

Im expecting the empty rectangle to disappear, what causes this and how can I get rid of it

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>



    <!-- COllapsible sidebar -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-1 " id="sidebar">
                <div class="list-group panel">
                    <!-- we start with a collpsible item -->
                    <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Item 1</span> </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="menu1">
                        <!-- this is the first expansion -->
                        <a href="#menu1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 1 </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1">
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 1 a</a>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 2 b</a>
                            <!-- This is the start of sub step -->
                            <a href="#menu1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1">
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                                <!-- this is another sub within the sub above -->
                                <a href="#menu1sub1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c.3 </a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1sub1">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 4 d</a>
                            <a href="#menu1sub1sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false">Subitem 5 e </a>
                            <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub2">
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.1</a>
                                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.2</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 2</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 3</a>
                    </div>




                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>




    <!-- end of collapsible sidebar -->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that it's supposed to be a down arrow or some other font that was not included, but you have not provided any custom CSS (`main.css`) that might be applied to the class `list-group-item` or to specific ids of this type (if any CSS exists for these selectors)

Comment: Because Fontawesome is not being loaded properly